# Can't run assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

So the project is basically about coding a calculator that can use the 4 basic operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, in assembly language. I'm sorry but the comments are written in French I guess you won't need them to understand the code anyway.

May help: My teacher said that I reported a stack segment that doesn't belong to where it is placed.
When I run the code I get these errors :

```
(56) error A2006: undefined symbol : scan_num
(89) error A2006: undefined symbol : scan_num
(100)error A2006: undefined symbol : do_plus
(103)error A2006: undefined symbol : do_minus
(106) error A2006: undefined symbol : do_mult
(109) error A2006: undefined symbol : do_div
(128) error A2006: undefined symbol : main
```

Here is my code:

```
SSEG  SEGMENT      STACK
      DB          32 DUP("STACK---")
SSEG  ENDS
;===========================================================code segment
            assume cs:cseg, ds:cseg, es:cseg
cseg        segment

            org 100h
;----------

name "CALCULATRICE"

PUTC    MACRO char
        PUSH AX
        MOV AL,char
        MOV AH, 0Eh
        INT 10h
        POP AX
ENDM

jmp start

;------------- Zone de donnée

msg0    db "BELLAL MOHAMED BUT1 2021/2022",0Dh,0Ah
        db "CALCULATOR3000 gerant les quatres opérations basiques ( + - * / )",0Dh,0Ah,"$"
msg1    db 0Dh,0Ah,0Dh,0Ah, "Entrer le premier terme de l'opération: $"
msg2    db "Choisissez l'opérateur à utiliser: + - * / : $"
msg3    db "Entrer le second terme de l'opération: $"
msg4    db 0Dh, 0Ah,"Le résultat est: $"
msg5    db 0Dh, 0Ah," ",0Dh,0Ah,"$"
err1    db "Saisie incorrecte",0Dh,0Ah,"$"
smth    db "Et .... $"

opr db "?" ; variable contenant l'opérateur

num1 dw ? ; variable contenant le premier terme de l'opération
num2 dw ? ; variable contenant le deuxième terme de l'opération

;--------------- PROGRAMME

start:
mov dx, offset msg0
mov ah, 9
int 21h

lea dx, msg1
mov ah, 09h     ; afficher le premier message
int 21h

; récupérer un nombre saisi par l'utilisateur et on le stock dans
; le registre CX

call scan_num

mov num1, cx ; stocker le nombre dans num1

; nouvelle ligne
putc 0Dh
putc 0Ah

lea dx, msg2
mov ah, 09h         ; affiche le deuxième message
int 21h

; récupérer l'opérateur
mov ah, 1
int 21h
mov opr, al

; nouvelle ligne
putc 0Dh
putc 0Ah

cmp opr, "q"        ; q pour quitter
je exit

cmp opr, "*"
jb wrong_opr
cmp opr, "/"
ja wrong_opr

lea dx, msg3
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

call scan_num

mov num2, cx

lea dx, msg4
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

;------------- CALCULER

cmp opr, "+"
je do_plus

cmp opr, "-"
je do_minus

cmp opr, "*"
je do_mult

cmp opr, "/"
je do_div

;---------- CAS PAR DEFAUT

wrong_opr:
lea dx, err1
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

exit:

lea dx, msg5
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov ah, 0

;---------
cseg        ends
            end main
```

Comment: You have an extra `END` on the 4th last line.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: If you removed that surely you got a different error?

Comment: Yes, without the "END" I get 7 "error A2006: undefined symbol" errors

Comment: Yeah well [edit] your question and show exactly what you get, at least the first one.

Comment: Those symbols are indeed not defined. Where is `scan_num` or `do_minus`? You can't use undefined symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Do you think you can help me complete my program to make it work? I am not very good at assembly, and I have to turn in the project very soon. I have done several searches on the internet but I can't find anything that can help me. Can you please help me?

Comment: By the way I solved the last error, but I need help for the rest of the program. I need help to code the functions that are in the errors please !

Comment: Please let me know if you are ok to do this.

Comment: Those undefined symbols seem to be additional code that you're trying to use, that's in another file. You can copy-paste those functions into this file, or you can use `include "filepath"` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a code label as an instruction operand, it needs to also exist somewhere in your code on its own line with a colon after it, or a `proc` statement if your assembler allows it.

You may have noticed that you didn't see a similar error message for `wrong_opr`. That's because you have that label in your source code.

```
cmp opr, "*"
jb wrong_opr
cmp opr, "/"
ja wrong_opr

; rest of your code

wrong_opr:    ;the 'jb' and 'ja' statements will take you here.
```

You got the error messages for the other labels because they're not in your program.

Here's how I'd fix it for now:

```
;--------------- PROGRAMME

start:
main:          ;add this here to "balance" your "end main"
mov dx, offset msg0
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

And then you can do the following. I purposely wrote this in a sub-optimal manner to make it easier to read.

```
cmp opr, "+"
je do_plus

cmp opr, "-"
je do_minus

cmp opr, "*"
je do_mult

cmp opr, "/"
je do_div
jmp wrong_opr   ;if none of the above, goto default



do_plus:
; your code for what happens when user types + goes here
jmp exit

do_minus:
; your code for what happens when user types - goes here
jmp exit

do_mult:
; your code for what happens when user types * goes here
jmp exit

do_div:
; your code for what happens when user types / goes here
jmp exit



;---------- CAS PAR DEFAUT

wrong_opr:
lea dx, err1
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

exit:

lea dx, msg5
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

; you need to put the exit code here or your computer will crash.
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h

;down here you can safely put any functions you wish
scan_num:
;you can put your code here for how you scan the user input

ret

;---------
end main   ;I'm not sure but I think these should be in this order.
cseg        ends
```

That should be enough to get those errors to go away. Of course, you'll still have to figure out how you want to accomplish the task.